# Competition: When will we hit 10,000 questions?

Tags: discussion, fun

You have two-ish weeks to enter, with a date and time  (UTC) for when you expect us to find question 10,000 on the front page.

Only <strike>two</strike> <strike>three</strike> four rules:

- write a date and time ([UTC](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/)) before the end of September, 2014
- you can't write the 10,000th question yourself.
- moderators are not allowed to participate (due to their access to statistical information about the site metrics).
- ONE guess allowed per user.

EDIT: Update - Dec 19, out of 14 guesses, 5 are now passed. 9 left in the running!

EDIT: Update - Jan 4, we're down to 6 active!

---

Now locked, good luck to all! :D

Comment: So? What's the prize? **What's the incentive for us to post an answer?** If you don't tell us what it is (or don't explicitly state that it's a surprise), we have absolutely no incentive to post an answer.

Comment: Er, you realise I'm just a user doing this for a bit of fun? It came up in the [chat].  And as shown below, people are plenty happy to post answers :/

Comment: Another rule: only your post's first revision should be considered, so retroactively editing your post or editing someone else's post will not count.

Comment: The question should include a link to a website that does the local time / UTC time conversion. Those of us who are too lazy, too busy at work, or with crappy internet would then be more inspired to enter.

Comment: @mindcorrosive you added a rule saying mods can't enter? I know what info you've got and don't think it'll really help you this far out ;)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi wait, first you're demanding incentives, now you're trying to add rules? :P
I think it's totally fine to edit your post up until the close date of the end of September.  All edits are visible and it'll be clear if anyone's trying to do something underhand afterwards, and we can revert edits.

Comment: @hippietrail http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/

Comment: Are questions like this allowed on meta?

Comment: I will award a 50 reputation bounty to the winner, and even 100 if it's within 24 hours.

Comment: @Dirty-flow shall we make it you have to have answered / asked a question in September to be eligible? :D

Comment: @MarkMayo I don't really like the idea - that could lead to some low-quality posts.

Comment: @Dirty-flow generally only experienced users in meta, they know low quality posts get downvotes ;)

Comment: @BobbyAlexander [It's been done before and widely accepted.](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/769/competition-when-will-we-hit-2000-questions)

Comment: How will the 10,000th question be determined?  Suppose there are multiple 10,000th questions (because after the 10,000th is asked, a question is deleted, then a new 10,000th is asked)?

Comment: @Flimzy that seems unlikely, but it'll be the latest question asked when our total questions is at 10,000.  If, after that, questions get deleted or something, well that's just bad luck.

Comment: @MarkMayo: It happened on Christianity.SE for question #666.... :)

Comment: @MarkMayo: BTW, the ability for deleted questions to change the count gives 10k+ rep users a slight advantage, too. If their guess is coming up, but not quite there, they could go through and delete some old, low-quality questions, to extend the contest a little longer.

Comment: @Flimzy and Mark Mayo (the OP): A better way to do it would be to use the question that is posted just after the site has 9,999 questions. This way, the answer remains fixed even if a question is deleted. An exception would be if that question happens to be spam/offensive (*very* unlikely), in which the question that counts is the earliest non-spam/offensive question posted after that.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: And what happens if the site has 9,999 questions more than once due to deletions?

Comment: @Flimzy As soon as it reaches 10k questions **the first time**, it's locked in. If it reaches exactly 10k questions again, those don't count.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: Sounds good in theory. I'm not sure how one would know when it happens, though.

Comment: @MarkMayo Have you flagged for a mod to put in a wiki answer lock? (Normal closure will put in the wrong effect, and locking for any other reason will also do the same. Additionally, protection won't do that much given that users must have 5 reputation *anyway* to post on meta)

Comment: Weren't you the one demanding incentives at the start, and now trying to clarify all sorts of rules? :)  I actually thought a mod had, I'll flag again, although even if someone did post late, we can all see the date stamps and would proceed to mock them for cheating ;)

Comment: Did anyone win the competition? Maybe there should be a new one for 11,000 questions :)

Comment: @JonathanReez see below, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### January 17th 2015 12:01am

:)

Comment: congrats, you won :)

Comment: Boom! Who's the daddy, you's all my bitches now

Comment: Nice work. I figured you were way late on that one!

Comment: Playing the law of averages, where was the biggest time frame I could slot into, 12 hours after @MarkMayo's :D Then ANYTHING higher than the highest was mine!

Comment: (cough weasel) ;)

Comment: @Liam I awarded you 50 rep bounty as I have promised :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess - with thousands of supercomputer hours crunched, tarot cards consulted, and ...oh stuff it, here goes nothing:

### January 16th, 2015, high noon.

Comment: @pnuts as many as you want, as long as they're quality on-topic travel questions :)

Answer (score 2):

My guess:

### January 10th, 2015 - Noon

Answer (score 2):

**January 11th,2015 - 12:00 UTC.**

Answer (score 1):

My revised guess,

### December 18th, 2014 - Noon

Answer (score 1):

I figure we'll have a little bit of a hats-induced Christmas surge, so I'm going for

### December 24th, 2014 - 4pm

Answer (score 1):

## December 11<sup>th</sup>

12:00 GMT

Answer (score 1):

## Dec 9th, 8pm UTC.

We appear to be getting at least 15 questions a day, and are at 8500, so 100 days from now, but then I took a little off because we're accelerating.

Answer (score 1):

### December 2nd, 2014 - 18:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1):

My guess

## December 22nd, 12:00 UTC

Answer (score 1):

My Guess

### January 6th, 2015 - 00:46 UTC

Comment: Whats with the 00:46??? a lucky number or something?

Comment: yes, 46 is my lucky number ;)

Comment: Plus it's Valentino Rossi! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess:

**January 9, 2015, 1:23am**

Answer (score 1):

## January 1st, 2015, 00:00:01 UTC.

Answer (score -2):

**January 20th 2015 - 20:04:49 UTC**

Comment: Sorry mate, no more guesses are accepted, check the OP.